# Can I define an element in css that then can assign text and image to it in html?

Tags: html, css, properties

I have a lot of HTML pages, and on those pages, I have many `div` elements with innder `div` and `img` and texts.
So I will have a structure like this repeated many times in my HTML pages:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="specific">
      <article class="item">
        <div class="thumb">
          <a href="URL1">
            <img src="IMAGE1" alt="ALT1" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <h2>
            <a href="URL2">Text sample 1</a>
          </h2>
          <div class="author">
            <div class="thumb">
              <img src="IMAGE2" alt="ALT2" />
            </div>
            <div class="gold">
              <h3>Text sample 2</h3>
              <p>Text sample 3</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If for every item that I have I add this structure my HTML code gets too long and difficult to read and does not look neat.

Can I create an element in CSS (or HTML itself) such that for each instance of the above structure I can just put the CSS element and add some properties to it like:

- URL1
- IMAGE1
- ALT1
- Text sample 1
- IMAGE2
- ALT2
- Text sample 2
- Text sample 3

and for another instance, I repeat this so my code looks cleaner and much smaller.

Answer (score 1):

This is what a framework(think *ngFor in Angular) is for but if you're looking to do it in vanilla HTML CSS JS, you can use javascript to create elements with custom values and append it to your root HTML element like this

HTML

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

CSS

```
.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

JS

```
const root = document.querySelector("#root");

values = ["hi", "hello", "hey"];

for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  // create element
  const newP = document.createElement("p");
  // update element
  newP.innerText = values[i];
  newP.classList.add('bg-red')

  // add element to root div
  root.appendChild(newP);
}
```

You can view this code in codepen [here](https://codepen.io/jspoh/pen/RwJVgBB)